# Passing an argument in a selector action

Tags: swift3, uigesturerecognizer, selector

Im trying to create a long press gesture recognizer with an action that passes a argument however I've encountered this error :

> Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property,
>   or initializer

the only thing I've tried so far is adding `@objc` at the beginning of the `removeDate` function as another post suggested with no luck.

```
let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeDate(deleteIndex: 3)))
            longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.00
            cell.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

func removeDate(deleteIndex: Int) {
    if deleteIndex != 0 {
        dates.remove(at: deleteIndex - 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass any other object with `GestureRecognizer` action, it will allow you to pass the only `UIGestureRecognizer` object nothing else. if you want the index of long press cell then you can try like this.

First set `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` action like this.

```
let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeDate(_:)))
longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.00
cell.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
```

Now set the `removeDate` action like this way.

```
func removeDate(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .began {
        let touchPoint = gesture.location(in: self.tableView)
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            print(indexPath)
            dates.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```